# cant seem to calculate everybody's score from a hashmap

Tags: list, hashmap, calculated-field

Hello fellow developers !

I'm trying to make a calculator for the score of all the players in a hashmap, I'm usign Bukkit.
The list itself is a team, (BlueTeam) and the scores are in a HashMap.
I've tried this:

```
private List<Player> blueteam = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Player allblue : blueteam) {
            int blueteamscore = score.get(allblue);
msg(sender, "blue teams score: " + blueteamscore);
}
```

But this returns me null, I've searched everywhere online and didn't find anything.

I think I need to calculate everybody's own score in that list and + them all together, but can't find a way to.
Thanks in advance for all the helpers !

Comment: Hello, possibly you should provide more code than a loop only, problem seems to be elsewhere. Plus cscore tag is for csharp music library.

Comment: Thanks, just did.
Do you know how to do it btw